# Netsuite-Suitelet post to restlet get parameters

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am executing a restlet by a post request in a suitelet. The restlet runs fine and I am able to pass data back from restlet--->suitelet, but I am unable to pass data from the suitelet to the restlet when I call the restlet.

suitelet

```
var test = 'test';
var parameters = {'custscripttest_input':test};
var apiURL='https://3864948- 
    sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl? 
    script=xxx&deploy=1';
    try{
       var restletResponse=https.post({
       url:apiURL,
       headers:header,
       body:postData,
       params:parameters
     });
```

restlet

```
    var testInput = 
    runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name:'custscripttest_input'});
```

No parameters show in runtime.getCurrentScript. I have created the parameter in the restlet script record.

I have also tried passing body data and retrieving in the restlet like so:

```
       var data = context.request.parameters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to have overlooked my body:postData format. My post data body structure in my suitelet was

```
var postData={input:{"cust_input": test}
```

I retrieved data in the restlet using context.input.cust_input;

Answer (score 0):

The params in an http(s) request are added to the url. They are not passed through to the script deployment parameters of the restlet.

Restlets don't give access to query string parameters when a body is included.
If you need the parameters you could format your postbody as:

```
body:JSON.stringify({
    params:parameters,
    body:postData // have postData still as an object at this point.
})
```